# is it acceptable to use ob_start()/ob_clean/ob_flush() to do error handling in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling

Is it acceptable to do error handling in php like below? I am not very familiar with `ob_start()/ob_clean()/ob_flush()`, so I want to known is there any bad effect to use them? for example, will they affect performance?

```
<?php 
    function custorErr()
    {
        ob_clean();
        //echo error message and some other error handling...
        die();
    }
    set_error_handler("custorErr");
    ob_start();

?>
<!doctype html>
<!-- html here -->
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        demo
    </body>
</html>
<?php ob_flush();?>
```

If this is not the best practice, then is there any better way to clear all the page content when there being error?

Comment: I'm actually not sure about this. Good quesiton! But I guess it would be a good idea to put the set_error_handler before using ob_start()

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I edited code in this question as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

I guess your approach would work very fine and if you want to use it repeatedly I think your approach is the best.

Another option is to put the buffering part in a `try/catch`-block. And then clean up output buffer if something goes wrong. If it's just one location you want to check this error , I believe this approach would be better.

```
<?php 
try {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <!-- html here -->
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            demo
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    ob_flush();
}
catch {Exception $e) {
    ob_end_clean(); //OR ob_clean();
    echo 'error is ' . print_r($e, true);
}
```

Some documentation about cleaning up output buffering:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php